# TextInput disables Key Bindings

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I have an app that uses several keyboard shortcuts (binded and unbinded dynamically, depending on situation) made using standard method:

```
xxx = Window.request_keyboard(self.turn_off, self, 'text')
xxx.bind(on_key_down=self.my_function)
```

Sadly the moment I added some fields of TextInput all my bindings stop working. Precisely bindings stop working when I mouse-click TextInput for the first time. After that even if I click outside TextInput field (thus defocusing it) my bindings are already gone.

What I need is for my key bindings to work all the time, regardless of whether TextInput field is active, was active, will be active or whatever else scenario there is. How can I do that?

I'm talking physical keyboard here and standard PC mouse + keyboard setup.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show your `self.turn_off` method? Maybe you use `unbind` method there?

Comment: Of course I have all unbinds in my self.turn_off method (including unbinding self.my_function from my example). Thing is, this method is never triggered (at least not by me) until program ends. Are You suggesting that focusing TextInput automatically triggers self.turn_off method somehow?

Comment: It's hard to say without the code. Can you provide a short example for us to analyse?